# "Windows Setup cannot find a location to store temporary installation files" when installing Server 2008 R2 on Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, installation, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to remotely install Windows Server 2008 R2 on a Server 2008 box using an iso image.

When I run the setup I get the error:

> ### Install Windows
>
> Windows Setup cannot find a location to store temporary installation files.
>   To install Windows, make sure that a partition on your boot disk has at 
>   least 834 megabytes (MB) of free space.
>
> > Error code: 0x80070490
>
> [OK]

There is plenty of space on both C: and D: and I've tried mounting the ISO (using Virtual Clone Drive) from both drives. I've also tried extracting the files from the ISO and running setup but I always get the same problem.

I thought the ISO file might be corrupt but I computed the SHA1 hash to be the same as the one listed on the MSDN download site.

If I had physical access to the machine I'd burn the ISO to a disk but I'm stuck with KVM remote access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the correct drivers loaded for the mass storage device that you are trying to install to.

Comment: Thanks. I checked and the drivers are up to date. And the current installation of Windows Server 2008 is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a partition in device disk manager before the C drive - I had a 200MB restore partition. Expanded it to 2000MB and upgrade went well.